# tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory Value Error: No images found

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

belos is my code to ensure that the folder has images, but tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory returns no images found. What did I do wrong? Thanks.

```
DATASET_PATH = pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\images')
image_count = len(list(DATASET_PATH.glob('.\\*.jpg')))
print(image_count)
```

output = 2715

```
batch_size = 4
img_height = 32
img_width = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATASET_PATH.name,
    validation_split=0.8,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)
```

output:

```
Found 0 files belonging to 0 classes.
Using 0 files for training.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tensorDataPreProcessed.py", line 23, in <module>
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image_dataset.py", line 200, in image_dataset_from_directory
    raise ValueError('No images found.')
ValueError: No images found.
```

Comment: When using `image_dataset_from_directory`  you folders need to have subfolders for each of the classes, i.e. `C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\images\\class_1`, `C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\images\\class_2`, etc

Comment: Hi @pavel, what if I only have one class? Do I still need to have a subfolder with class_1?

Comment: And what do you plan to do with 1 class? How do you plan to train the model? How will it calculate a loss? At the very least you need to have images of some category and images that do not belong to this category, i.e. "cars" and "not_cars".

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Yes. there will be 2 classes. Thanks

Comment: Also, I plan to create a DCGAN using one fo the class. Hence, my comment earlier.

Comment: For a GAN you need the model to recognize the image class that you want to generate and thus it needs to know what **IS NOT** what you're trying to generate.

Comment: Thanks, it works after the directory has subfolders. Thanks again.

Comment: if you want to reply to the post, I can mark it and close the ticket. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues here, firstly `image_dataset_from_directory` requires subfolders for each of the classes within the directory. This way it can automatically identify and assign class labels to images.

So the standard folder structure for TF is:

```
data
|
|___train
|      |___class_1
|      |___class_2
|
|___validation
|      |___class_1
|      |___class_2
|
|___test(optional)
       |___class_1
       |___class_2
```

The other issue is that you are attempting to create a model using only one class which is not a way to go. The model needs to be able to differentiate between the class you are trying to generate using GAN but to do this it needs a sample of images that **do not** belong to this class.

Comment: I try to replicate transfert style from this exemple https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer We don't need 2 class for trainning only load 2 picture to merge it. Does I have to create a "class" style dirctory where my class will be for exemple "style" and "target" ??

Comment: Unless, of course, you're doing unsupervised learning, such as VACs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing unsupervised learning and you genuinely only have one class then there is an argument for `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` called `labels`:

**NOTE:** *If you're unsure whether this applies to your problem you should become sure first. Just copying this solution without knowing if it's what your problem needs is a bad idea.*

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory):

> **labels:** Either "inferred" (labels are generated from the directory structure), None (no labels), or a list/tuple of integer labels of the same size as the number of image files found in the directory. Labels should be sorted according to the alphanumeric order of the image file paths (obtained via os.walk(directory) in Python).

So you can set labels to `None` and it'll import all images into 1 class.